# Can $\ce{CaCO3}$ shells contribute to $\ce{CO2}$ emissions in volcanoes within subduction zones?

Tags: geochemistry, co2, carbon-cycle, subduction

CaCO<sub>3</sub> dissolves below the [Carbonate Compensation Depth (CCD)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carbonate_compensation_depth).

However, [this paper](https://pubs.geoscienceworld.org/sepm/books/book/1144/chapter-abstract/10571036/Preservation-of-Foraminifera?redirectedFrom=PDF) suggests that some CaCO<sub>3</sub> can exist below the CCD.

My question arises from a discussion in [this answer](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/a/25052/28185).

The question is whether some of the CO<sub>2</sub> emitted by volcanoes in subduction zones comes from the melting of CaCO<sub>3</sub> sediments in the slag.

Has there been any isotopic study clarifying the provenance of CO<sub>2</sub> from volcanoes in subduction zones?

Comment: You're fundamentally misunderstanding what the CCD is. It is a depth *in the ocean*. It has nothing to say about CaCO3 as part of rocks.

Comment: @Wolfgang Bangert When the plate subdcuts they are mostly CaCO3 sediments, not rocks.

Comment: CaCO3 sediments *are* rocks: Limestone. It even has the name "stone" in the word.

Comment: @Wolfgang Bangerth No, sediments are not rocks until diagenesis happens

Comment: @Universal_learner When geologists refer to "sediments" they include sedimentary rocks in that. An unconsolidated calcium carbonate sediment is called "calcareous ooze".

Comment: @Universal_learner Like Spencer already said, you're splitting hairs. But specifically, even after diagenesis, it's still CaCO3.

Comment: @Spencer To me sediments are not rocks. I read in [this paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S007045710871046X) about oceanic limestones diagenesis. The question title may not very good, I modified it, as the questions arises the question if CaCO3 is dissolved bellow the CCD.  That brings me to new questions. How much of CaCO3 lithiphied is dissolved? And Are only sediments dissolved bellow the CCD but lithiphied rocks not?